# JJJJJOOOP.. sound

Tags: design, sound, synthesis, app

I've been hired by someone developing a messaging APP and he wants a sound for when a message is sent and a message is received. It's hard to describe over text, but it would sound like "JJJJJOOOP" going up in pitch to send a message, and to receive a message, another jjjjooop, but going down in pitch.

I'm not really a sound designer, I just DJ and know my way around ableton, so he asked me for this.

please forgive my ignorance!

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Frequency modulation is your friend.  Hit a note on a keyboard and then do a frequency modulation sweep either up or down.  Select instrument to your liking.

Answer (score 1):

May i suggest recording you hititng a ping pong racket over the end of a tube.

Answer (score 0):

Record your mouth doing a bunch a bunch of variations of it, process it to make it metallic or bell resonant or filtered after that.

Surprise, voila, you've got it.

Comment: it's friday night y'all this is the best I can do